# How to Sum the duration and display it in Report

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
Public Function TotalHoursWorked() As IEnumerable(Of Reporting.EmployeeViewModel) Implements IReportRepository.TotalHoursWorked**

    Dim qryEmployee = From emp In db.Employee _
    .Select(Function(emp) New With {emp.EmployeeId, emp.EmployeeName}).AsEnumerable

    Dim qryHoursWorked = From hw In db.HoursWorked
                             Select New With {hw.EmployeeId, hw.HoursWorkedStart, hw.HoursWorkedEnd}

    Return (From emp In qryEmployee _
            Join hw In qryHoursWorked On emp.EmployeeId Equals hw.EmployeeId _
            Select New Reporting.EmployeeViewModel With {
                 .EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName,
                 .HoursWorkedStart = RoundClockInTime(hw.HoursWorkedStart),
                 .HoursWorkedEnd = If(hw.HoursWorkedEnd.HasValue, RoundClockOutTime(hw.HoursWorkedEnd), hw.HoursWorkedEnd),
                 .HoursWorked = (.HoursWorkedStart - .HoursWorkedEnd),
                 .TotalHours = Sum(.HoursWorked)
             })

End Function
```

The error I am getting is `"Sum is either not declared or not in the current scope"`. I need to display the total hours in my report footer grouped by employeeId.

Any sugestions regarding this.Where I might be going wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I can help you, but just to make things easier can you let me know what exactly db.Employee and db.HoursWorked consist of? Are you selecting anonymous types because you don't need/want all of the additional properties?

Answer (score 0):

Right, VB.Net is not my language (regular c#) so if there are any mistakes forgive me.

It seems that to start with you have an odd mix of query syntax and fluent syntax going on there which you need to be careful with. Also the `AsEnumerable` I think is not necessary.

It also doesn't make sense to have a number of EmployeeViewModels each with seperate working hours but also a total which would be formed from other ViewModels as well. How would you display that? Either the total should be calculated later for the report or you need to change the ViewModel to have a list of WorkingHours and a Total. Also you should not set the HoursWorked here it should be a read only property which returns the calculated value.

My first suggestion for you would be a [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531303.aspx). Sum is not available without either grouping or using Aggregates.

So my solution would be as follows:

```
Dim Employees = From Employee In db.Employee
                Select New With 
                {
                    .EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId,
                    .Name = Employee.EmployeeName
                }

Dim WorkingHours = From HoursWorked In db.HoursWorked
                  Select New With 
                  {
                      .EmployeeId = HoursWorked.EmployeeId,
                      .Start = HoursWorked.HoursWorkedStart
                      .End = HoursWorked.HoursWorkedEnd
                  }

Dim EmployeeWorkingHours = From Employee In Employees
                          Group Join HoursWorked In WorkingHours
                          On Employee.EmployeeId Equals HoursWorked.EmployeeId
                          Into EmployeeHoursWorked = Group, _
                              TotalHours = Sum(HoursWorked.Start - HoursWorked.End)
                          From EmployeeHours in EmployeeHoursWorked
                          Select New Reporting.EmployeeViewModel With
                          {
                              .EmployeeName = Employee.Name
                              .HoursWorkedStart = EmployeeHours.Start
                              .HoursWorkedEnd = EmployeeHours.End
                              .HoursWorked = (EmployeeHours.Start - EmployeeHours.End)
                              .TotalHours = CType(TotalHours, Integer?) _
                                  .GetValueOrDefault(0)
                          }
```

Now if you follow the above and make a new class e.g. WorkingHours with properties Start, End, and a read only property HoursWorked which returns (Start - End).

Then you can have a Total property on the EmployeeViewModel which will use LINQ if you like to sum the HoursWorked to give your Total.

More Like:

```
Dim WorkingHours = From HoursWorked In db.HoursWorked
                  Select New WorkingHours With 
                  {
                      .EmployeeId = HoursWorked.EmployeeId,
                      .Start = HoursWorked.HoursWorkedStart
                      .End = HoursWorked.HoursWorkedEnd
                  }

Dim EmployeeWorkingHours = From Employee In Employees
                          Group Join HoursWorked In WorkingHours
                          On Employee.EmployeeId Equals HoursWorked.EmployeeId
                          Into EmployeeHoursWorked = Group
                          Select New Reporting.EmployeeViewModel With
                          {
                              .EmployeeName = Employee.Name
                              ' This is an Enumerable<WorkingHours>
                              ' which you can use in the ViewModel
                              ' to calculate the total.
                              .WorkingHours = EmployeeHoursWorked
                          }
```

Comment: I die exactly like your code and still I get the error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible Sum can be called with these argruments: My code is

Comment: I did exactly like your code and still I get the error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible Sum can be called with these argruments: Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, Decimal?)) As Decimal?' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.TimeSpan?' cannot be converted to 'Decimal?'. I have other fields of Type Long, string, Double, DateTime etc which I deleted due to space problem.

Comment: Well, The first one I think you need to update your question with the new code you have tried before I can help. The other one is simple you are trying to convert TimeSpan? to Decimal? which is not valid. Post what you tried and I will help.